# how to select MYSQL from count and group by date range a week

Tags: mysql

I want to make grafik every week, from my table from the result of count and I want to get date group date

```
SELECT date(created_at) x , jumlah_data as y 
FROM(
    select  created_at, count(*) as jumlah_data 
    from (
        select kontrakid,created_at, tahapan_kontrak as tahapan_usulan 
        from histori_summary a 
        where tahapan_kontrak_id = 7 AND IFNULL(tahapan_kontrak_is_setuju, 1) !=0 
        GROUP BY kontrakid
    ) s
) d  
WHERE date(created_at) >= '2021-09-16' and date(created_at) <= curdate() 
GROUP BY date(created_at)
```

but this query only view one rows not all or seven rows.

Comment: You're missing `GROUP BY created_at` in `d` subquery, so everything is being aggregated into a single row.

Comment: i have added created GROUP BY created_at in d or is s but the result still only one rows, i want to show 7 rows

Comment: You must have done it wrong. Edit the question and add the new query (don't remove the original code).

Comment: You don't even need the outer query. Add the date restriction to the inner `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need so many levels of nesting. Put the date restriction in the inner subquery. This will also make the query more efficient, since it won't group things that are going to be discarded in the outer queries.

```
select DATE(created_at) AS created_date, count(*) as jumlah_data 
from (
    select kontrakid,created_at
    from histori_summary a 
    where tahapan_kontrak_id = 7 AND IFNULL(tahapan_kontrak_is_setuju, 1) !=0 
    and date(created_at) >= '2021-09-16' and date(created_at) <= curdate()
    GROUP BY kontrakid
) s
GROUP BY created_date
```

There's also no need to select `tahapan_kontrak`, since it's not being used by the outer queries.